# Iavascript \" \' I'm confused

Tags: javascript, dom-events, escaping, quotes

I'm busy on little JavaScript item, but I got confused by the next rule:

```
<a href="#" onclick="removeMap('+ \"test\" +')" style="float:right; margin-right: 30px;"><img src="images/icons/collapse.gif"></a><br/>'
```

It doesn't take the `onclick` remove map action. I don't know what I have to put between the `()` to make I can put text there. Does somebody have the solution?

Answer (score 8):

Try just :

```
onclick="removeMap('test')"
```

if test is a `variable`:

```
onclick="removeMap(test)"
```

The `\"` is to scape the closing double quote of the `onclick` event. In this case I don't see any use in your calling. When used event functions in the html tags just like your onclick event, as html uses `double quotes` for the attributes you need to use the single quotes in your `inline` `javascript` functions.

---

By the way, have you checked about [`JQuery` JavaScript Library](http://jquery.com/). As you are starting coding `javascript` it's good to know your options.

Answer (score 2):

Or just stop writing javascript inside of your HTML tags, just call functions and put your code in your functions... far much readeable !

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<a href="#" onclick="removeMap('test')" style="float:right; margin-right: 30px;"><img src="images/icons/collapse.gif"></a><br/>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an editor that properly highlights strings (and what is going on should be obvious)

Answer (score 0):

Escaped quotes don't have any special meaning in HTML. Instead, the browser will see your line as:

```
<a href="#"
  onclick="removeMap('+ \"
  test\
  " +')"
  style="float:right; margin-right: 30px;"
>
```

Where the `onclick` would be broken Javascript, and there would be two attributes in the tag (`test\` and `" +')"`) that it doesn't recognize and doesn't know what to do with.